# JavaScript equivalent of C# TCPclient sending

Tags: javascript, c#

I am experimenting on sending data from a C# application into a TCP server and get the response from it, just wondering if there's a JavaScript command or framework equivalent to TCP client to server communication? Below is the C# code that i am using, this code works fine but i am planning to create a web application.

```
private void sendDataToTCPServer()
        {

            string message =  "Hello Server!";

            string IP = ip_text.Text;
            int port =  server_port.Text); 
            try
            {

                TcpClient client = new TcpClient(IP, port); 


                Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);


                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();


                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);



                data = new Byte[256];


                String responseData = String.Empty;


                Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);

                responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);

                Message.Show(resposeData);
                stream.Close();
                client.Close();
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException an)
            {


                MessageBox.Show(String.Format("ArgumentNullException: {0}", an.Message), "PLC Error Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {


                MessageBox.Show(String.Format("SocketException: {0}", se.Message), "PLC Error Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);


            }
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

You could just host an asp.net web app using what you have?

Here's a js example: https://gist.github.com/tedmiston/5935757